# How to set controls to an xbox controller

Tags: javascript, controller

SOO, you know how you can move stuff using basic java-script 2d stuff and your arrow keys. is it possible to change those arrow keys to a xbox controller, and if it is, how would a person go about doing it. for example, to move a square left you would use a joystick, or even simpler the d pad, or buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know is there any way to do it with code but I think the best way will be using some software to bind joystick moves to the keyboard like [this one](https://joytokey.net/en/), there are plenty of other softs, find another one if you don't like this